# Why is g++ not producing a binary?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

This is my build log when using Eclipse and GCC.

I have tried every suggestion for this issue I have found on the web (and there are lots!) but nothing works for me.

Can anyone see any issue from this build log please:

```
17:49:24 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project test2 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -o "src\\test2.o" "..\\src\\test2.cpp" 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\test2.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ -dD ..\src\test2.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test2.cpp -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase-strip src\test2.o -g3 -O0 -Wall -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\cc2tQ3YT.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 1ebc2a6f92fbd3aadc367a20a63fdf9f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\test2.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o src\test2.o C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\cc2tQ3YT.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\test2.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'

17:49:24 Build Finished (took 313ms)
```

Comment: To much information! All we really need is the actual commands used to compile and link the program, the compiler version, and a list of errors if you have any. And maybe the program *is* created, but not where you think it is?

Comment: Looks like the command was: `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -o "src\\test2.o" "..\\src\\test2.cpp"`
and it seems to complete fine, so the object file test2.o should have appeared in the src directory. Is it not present there?

Comment: Not test2.o is not anywhere on my drive - search for it incase it was elsewhere. And I switched off anti-virus, so that is not zapping the file